# How to set onClickListener for AutocompleteSupportFragment without overriding the normal behaviour

Tags: android, kotlin, onclicklistener, autocompletesupportfragment

I have an AutocompleteSupportFragment:

```
val asf = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.support_fragment)
            as AutocompleteSupportFragment
```

which looks like this:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/support_fragment"
    android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"
/>
```

I want to make a log when user taps (clicks) on it, but I don't want to change the expected behaviour: I still want users to be able to start the normal search as soon as they click it.

Comment: You can achieve instance of fragment right? so you can get container view by fragment.getView(), I'm not sure about container view group of AutocompleteSupportFragment content, but you can loop to get child elements

Comment: What do you mean about `it` in this sentence: `when user taps (clicks) on it`? Do you mean `when the user clicks on a place of the list` or something else?

Comment: @aminography Good question :) No, user usually 1) taps on the AutocompleteSupportFragment so that the keyboard pops up 2) types something on the keyboard so that a list of suggestions are shown 3) clicks (taps) on one of the suggested places. I meant the first step